# Xamarin.Plugin.Calender disable date

Tags: xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I am using xamarin.plugin.calendar. but I don't know the delegate method for disabling the past dates. anyone know this method for this. Kindly help me thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi , you can show a viedo about this phenomenon , I think this wil be helpful about solving it .

Comment: Why do you have two extra rows at end, since you are not using I mean  grid.row="3" & grid.row="4". You are not using these two

Comment: Hi, if previous problem is solved , remember to mark it . If have new question, you can recreate one to ask , then other people will see it .Now if change question , then follow answers will look very messy.

Comment: i unable to post question.

Comment: @PrissyEve Okey , it's strange .

Comment: can u answer my above question

Comment: @PrissyEve It seems like `xamarin.plugin.calendar` can not disabling the past dates.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for sharing video.This phenomenon is normal , because here the contained ListView's height is default , it will not be changed by the count of its cell .

Here is a sample **WorkAround** : when tapping up option , you can dynamically change the height of **ListView** ,as follow:

```
listview.HeightRequest = heightSize;
```

By the way, `heightSize` need to be calculated when view showing. According to video , if every cell of listview is defauld height, you just need to get count of it. Then you can know the height of listview.

Note: If this workaround is not fit for you, maybe you should do as Bruno's suggestion that re-layouting interface.

Comment: @PrissyEve Hi, does it work for you ? Just need to set Listview's Height , layout's Height will fit the ListView .

Comment: @PrissyEve If answer be helpful , thanks for voting up in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To solve that you need to rework your code, and don't use ScrollView and Nested ListViews.

You can have a scrollview and, for example, Bindable Layouts (Stacklayout), to mimick the Listview.

Comment: I am new to xamarin. how to mimick all layouts to listview